# You are in Jonathan’s circles: "too" or "as well" or "also"?

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis, sentence-ends, also-too

I just read on Google+ that:

> You are in Jonathan’s circles too

But I always thought that you couldn't use *too* there. Am I wrong? (because Google can't be wrong, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be a comma missing.

> You are in Jonathan's circles, too.

Either way, this is the usage of "too" as a synonym for "as well" or "also".

Comment: They all work there? Hmm, never knew that.

Comment: The original sentence is correct with or without the comma. ES&L would actually say that this comma is unecessary as it doesn't separate a clause, but instead denotes a place where a speaker would pause or change inflection (which can be inferred in context without aid). But your main point is correct; "too", "as well" and "also" are virtually synonymous.