# When can I use "as well" as a synonym for "too" or "also"?

Tags: word-usage, also-too

I remember that I can use "as well" as a synonym for "too" (or "also").

Is there any case in which I **can't** do this?

Am I safe using either of them?

---

This is partly related to these questions:

- [You are in Jonathan's circles "too" or "as well" or "also"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33920/you-are-in-jonathans-circles-too-or-as-well-or-also)
- [The correct usage of "too" and "also"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30366/the-correct-usage-of-too-and-also)
- ["Also" and "as well" for conversational context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399/also-and-as-well-for-conversational-context)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While "as well" has the same meaning as "also" or that sense of "too", you've fairly limited in when it can be used. Itt can only be used at the end of sentences or the end of complete thoughts.

```
I'd like the chicken as well.
```

This isn't alright:

```
I, as well, want the chicken.
As well, I want the chicken.
```

Of course, you'd go with:

```
I, too, want the chicken.
I also want the chicken.
I want the chicken, too.
I want the chicken, also.
```

I'd say it's just a slightly more formal, less useful version of "also" or "too."

Comment: Is "I, as well, want the chicken." really that bad? It sounds equivalent to "I, too, want the chicken.", in that it emphasizes that the speaker, and not someone else, wants the chicken.

Comment: @Hacksworth I agree with you that it would be useful for emphasis, but it's just not a natural-sounding phrase for an English speaker IMO. If you want that kind of emphasis, using "I, too" accomplishes it just as well.

Comment: "I, as well, want..." is truly *awful* English, even if it's not easy to explain exactly why to a non-native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I disagree. It’s certainly a highly marked usage, so there are relatively few contexts in which it would be appropriate, and I’d not go so far as actually to *recommend* it, but ‘truly *awful* English’ it is not. It *would* sound better as ‘I, as well, would like’, though, with a more formal verb.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: By all means prove me wrong. Find or create an example context where it *wouldn't* be awful. [Here's a start](http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22i+as+well+want%22), being the only 9 instances in google books. They all look awful to me, and most seem to be by authors with decidedly foreign-looking names.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Since it’s a matter of taste, there is obviously no question of proving you wrong. You are mistaken about the names, however: only *U Pandita*, *Silvan Teodoro*, and *Abdellah Benahnia* are foreign-looking. *Zillah* is an Old Testament and Hebrew name that in combination with *Eisenstein* suggests an American Jewish background. Benahnia is the co-author with Tim Avants of a guide to English grammar and syntax, and there's no way to tell who was responsible for that particular example in the book. (cont'd.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: (Cont'd.) In any case, a little time spent with Google clearly shows that the construction sounds fine to a great many native speakers, especially when they want to sound a bit formal (e.g., ‘I as well want to thank ...’).

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Fair enough. I don't much like it in *any* context, but I'll admit I find it slightly less grating when "as well" refers to additional *things* I want to speak of, rather than the "me too" meaning of Jeremy's examples. I'd like to hope the usage won't catch on, but people will say whatever they want, in the end.

Comment: I as well want to agree with FumbleFingers. Ugly English. It sounds like someone who is not terribly conversant with the language is trying to sound smart. Surely Strunk and White would both have hated such a construction?

Comment: "As well" does indicate a higher level of formality than either "too" or "also." IMO, it's unfortunate (not exactly awful :) that many US speakers use it in an attempt to sound cultivated. It just sounds rather silly to my ears, causing involuntary internal unseen eye-rolling.

Comment: What I do find **awful** is an error that I come across far too often, even in places quite respectable: "Mr. X was **also** involved in the incident as **well**"...

Comment: "As well" can be useful for breaking up monotony when writing: If you find yourself with two "also's" in close proximity, quite often a little rearrangement of a sentence, and substitution of "as well" for the second "also" will make things much smoother.